# sequential $US$-space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence

A topological space is called a US-space provided that
each convergent sequence has a unique limit.
the notion of strongly KC-spaces, that is, those spaces
in which every countably compact subset is closed.

**If $(X,‎\tau‎ )$ is a sequential $US$-space, then $X $ is strongly $ KC$.**

**P r o o f .** Let $A$ be a countably compact subset of $X$. If $A $ is not closed, since
$(X,‎\tau‎ )$ is a sequential space, there is some $x \in \operatorname{cl}(A) - A$ and a sequence $ \{x_{n} \}_{n \in ‎\omega} ⊂$
A convergent to $x$. Since $A$ is countably compact, $ \{x_{n} : n ∈‎ \omega  \}$ must have an
accumulation point $y$ in $A$ and so $ \{ x_{n} : n ∈ ‎\omega \} ∪ \{x \} $is not closed in $X$. Again since
$X$ is sequential, it follows that there is some sequence $ \{x_{n_{k}} : k ∈ ‎\omega \} ⊂ \{x_{n} : n ∈ ‎\omega \}$
which converges to $x′$ and $x′ \not\in \{x_{n} \} ∪ \{x\}$. Then $ \{ x_{n_{k}} : k ∈ ‎\omega \} $ must also converge 
to $x$, contradicting the definition of$ US$-space. Therefore, $X $is strongly $KC$.

> Why $ \{ x_{n} : n ∈ ‎\omega \} ∪ \{x \} $is not closed in $X$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $S=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}\cup\{x\}$. I don't immediately see why $S$ is not closed, but we don't need this to make the argument work. Suppose that $S$ is closed; $y$ is an accumulation point of $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$, so $y\in\operatorname{cl}\{x_n:n\in\omega\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}S$. And $y\ne x$ (since $x\notin A$), so $y=x_m$ for some $m\in\omega$.

Let $S'=\{x_n:n>m\}\cup\{x\}$; clearly $S'$ is not closed, since $x_m\in(\operatorname{cl}S')\setminus S$, and $\langle x_n:n>m\rangle$ still converges to $x$. Thus, there is some $x'\in(\operatorname{cl}S')\setminus S'$ and some subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\omega\rangle$ of $\langle x_n:n>m\rangle$ converging to $x'$, and the proof can be completed as before.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same thing. I also didn't see why $S$ would not be closed, i.e. why some $x_k$ could not already be the required accumulation point.... This argument is from a published paper (http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/140482/CzechMathJ_59-2009-2_3.pdf) lemma 3.10...

Comment: I thought we  have must proved that $ y \not\in \{ x_{n}   : n\in \omega \}. is it right? I do not see why you suppose that S  is closed!!

Comment: @fatemeh proving $S$ is *not* closed was your question!

Comment: excuse me. I mixed two questions.

Comment: Do you use from US property to say that "there is some x ′ ∈(clS ′ )∖S ′   and some subsequence $⟨x_{ n_{ k}}  :k∈ω⟩$  of $⟨x_{ n} :n>m⟩$  converging to x ′?

Comment: @fatemeh: No, that follows from the fact that the space is sequential and $S'$ is not closed.