# When a sequential space has unique sequential limits?

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is called a sequential space if a set $A \subset X$ is closed if and only if together with any sequence it contains all its limits.

so, according to definition, is the following correct?

> Sequential space has unique sequential limit iff each countably compact subset is closed.( and hence sequential).

Comment: The definition you gave doesn't quite make sense.  (What does "together with any sequence it contains all its limits" mean?)  See the definition at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space for a properly-stated definition.

Comment: @Daniel: Ebi’s English is a bit shaky. That’s intended to be a paraphrase of *if and only if together with any convergent sequence in A, A contains the limit(s) of that sequence*.

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467577/sequential-space

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Martin: I’m calling this one a duplicate of the one that you found: that one certainly literally answers the question here, and the answer even includes most — quite possibly all — of the explanation that I’d have given in addition to the bare *yes*.

Comment: Here is another question about the same thing: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464457/sequential-us-space